# Wordpress Bulk Update Post Content by Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, custom-post-type

I am using a custom post type in my Wordpress install called 'profiles'. I have a custom plugin that creates the type and then pre-fills the custom post type with the content I want visible on EVERY instance of that CPT. See below:

```
function profile_content_write() {
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'profiles'
    );

$pages = get_posts( $args );

foreach( $pages as $page ){
$post = array(
    'ID'           => $page->ID,
    'post_content' => 'page content...',
  );
wp_update_post( $post );
  }
}

add_action( 'init', 'profile_content_write' );
```

However, from time to time I will need to modify the default content. While new posts using the 'profiles' type will feature the new content (if I change my plugin code above), existing posts will NOT.

Anyone have an effective way to update the content of a post type? I am fine modifying the content by updating a plugin. Alternatively, I am comfortable making a menu item that can run the update. I am just unsure of HOW to update the content.

**Note**: I do not want to "append" content, but "rewrite content." Also, I will NOT write content in this post type outside what is displayed through the plugin function.

Comment: I don't understand your problem or question. If you want to update your CPTs with new content, just run your code again?

Comment: @Michael Yeah, that is what needed to happen. I thought I was doing something wrong, do to a problem in my code. Whenever I deactivated and then reactivated the plugin, only a few posts, if any, would update to the new `'post-content'`. What made it work was specifying `'numberposts' => -1` in the `$args = array()`. Now all post content will update to what I specify in the plugin file. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, but `numberposts` is a depreceated argument for WP_Query, instead you should use `posts_per_page`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED, WORKING CONTENT**

This works by activating and then deactivating the plugin files. Activating it rewrites all CPT post content. To update the content, modify the plugin file, then reactivate/deactivate.

```
function profile_content_write() {
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'profiles',
        'numberposts' => -1
    );

$pages = get_posts( $args );

foreach( $pages as $page ){
$post = array(
    'ID'           => $page->ID,
    'post_content' => 'page content...',
  );
wp_update_post( $post );
  }
}

add_action( 'init', 'profile_content_write' );
```